Model/sample/best questions wiki
I was going through this question Do the neural substrates behind motivation to retain/dispose of property govern whether certain people view their friends and partners as possessions?. and it struck me as a good example of the kind of questions we should encourage/promote on our site .It would be good to have a list/template set of questions. 
    Meta guidelines take some effort to read and comprehend, which turns off some types of people. I guess for repeat visitors/persistent people it may not be a problem, but for others it's too much of a time investment.(Most of these are immediately applicable for non-native English speakers, but i suspect, there are others too.) 
In contrast, examples give a quick intuition(implicit ideas/theories) of what is expected of the questioner. 
So let's have a thread with a list of examples of good questions.  We can make it a community wiki. 
Specifically in this question,he follows a structure/sequence, i find impressive/useful. 
    - Original/first thought/phrasing of the question as it occurred to him.
    - Actions taken towards finding a solution/answer.
    - Summary of research/publications he found that support and help refine the question, by rephrasing, introducing terminology etc.
    - What kind of answers he's looking for? More research papers with different approaches/viewpoints? Summary/survey papers of existing research? 


We have a discussion on this here you should consider contributing to it. We have also discussed previously on meta of making a question to highlight best posts in a given idea-thread or sub-topic, so that we could use it for advertising. I can't find where we had this discussion, but the first paragraph here is related.

@ArtemKaznatcheev: I indeed was looking for that discussion. I saw the old question, but feel this does not  fit there. After all, the main topic/focus of that thread, was how to ask a good question and am trying to focus on encouraging good questions.

the best way to encourage is by example. Take the time to ask more question on the main site! Our numbers have been wavering, and I think we'd all love to see more activity!

Actually, I have to give a lot of credit for that question to our own @ArtemKaznatcheev as he gave me some tips on the organization of it.  I will admit it's probably a good example of how edits can really shape up a post.
